# Python: Converting JSON entry to a SQL command ( divided by columns and attributes)

Tags: python, sql, json

New in Python. 
I am trying to convert JSON files to SQL files, but JSON file it's to complex with many entries, the structure it's like this:

```
['{"category": "new", "id": 1, "Name": ["Tester1"], "properties": {"host": "xxx", "type": "yyy", "device": null, "serial": "ddddd", "manufacturer": "vvvv"}}\n,']
```

... next entry....

I have a list, my final objective is to get something like this t then import with SQL commands:

```
Columns: category | id | Name | host| type | device | serial |manufacturer

Attributes:  new  | 1  | Tester1 | xxxx | yyy | null | dddd| yyyy
```

Any ideas to start?

Thank you.

Comment: Please use proper formatting on your questions...

Comment: Thank you all for editing and help me, i am sorry LeoE.

Comment: First, parse your string using `json.loads()`; then you have a data structure that you can print out in any form you want (it is not obvious to me what you mean by "SQL command" here - an INSERT?)

Comment: Yes for example, this is only 1 entry i want then create tables and insert information. for this case it's a INSERT.